# Conditional WHERE Statement in Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, report, ms-access-2010, subreport

I have a subreport in Access 2010 that lists projects based on criteria from a search form.  In this form, the user can select a ProjNo, or leave it blank.  If there's a ProjNo then the subreport should only print that one.  If it's blank, then it should show all of them.

I'm trying to set up an SQL that will do this.  The problem I'm having, though, is that when I try to search for all projects - ie. ProjNo is left blank in the search form - it only shows me the information for the first project.

```
SELECT Index.ProjNo, Index.Year, Index.Route, Index.Area, 
Index.[Value], Index.[Updated], 
Index.Page, Val(Nz([route],0)) AS routeNum
FROM [Index]
WHERE (((IIf([Activity].[ProjNo]<>"",[Index].[ProjNo]=[Activity].[ProjNo],
[Activity].[ProjNo] IS NULL));
```

I'm not very good at SQL, so any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LIKE` and `IIF()` or `NZ()`.

Example A:
`WHERE ProjNo LIKE IIF(searchProjNo="","*",searchProjNo)`

Example B:
`WHERE ProjNo LIKE NZ(searchProjNo,"*")`

Note: This approach can work well with parameterized queries, where the user can elect to view one record, all records, or a subset of records (ex., by using wildcards such as 123? or 1*).

Comment: This still gives me the same problem.

Comment: What is "[Activity].[ProjNo]"? You indicate that you are pulling a search criterion from a form field; is the SQL you've given the actual record source for the subreport? I don't think your problem statement has enough information.

Comment: There's two tables: Activity, and Index. Activity.ProjNo is the value that the search form pulls when a project number is typed in. The subform uses the Index table. The original SQL is everything up to the WHERE line; it ends at `FROM [INDEX]`.

Comment: Lets simplify things. Basic query: `SELECT * FROM INDEX`; query which selects on project number from form field: `SELECT * FROM INDEX WHERE INDEX.ProjNo=Forms![SearchDialog]![CriteriaField_ProjNo]`; query which (should) show either a) all projects or b) just the project number which was entered: `SELECT * FROM INDEX WHERE INDEX.ProjNo LIKE NZ(Forms![SearchDialog]![CriteriaField_ProjNo],"*")`.

Comment: The last part is like saying `IIF(Forms![SearchDialog]![CriteriaField_ProjNo]="","*",Forms![SearchDialog]![CriteriaField_ProjNo])`, which would translate into `{WHERE INDEX.ProjNo LIKE "*"}` or `{WHERE INDEX.ProjNo LIKE {whatever project number was entered in the form field}}`. Try making a query to that effect, then if it works, copy it into the subreport's record source property.

Comment: I got it to work! I did it by using the IIF statement. Thank you SO much!

Comment: would this approach work for inbetween dates or everything ?

Answer (score 1):

Forget the conditional part.  Just use regular boolean operators:

```
WHERE [Activity].[ProjNo] = "" OR
      [Index].[ProjNo] = [Activity].[ProjNo]
```

Comment: This still gives me the same problem.

Comment: It seems like when I include reference to Activity.ProjNo, it only gives me the first project when I want all of them. When I don't, it shows all of them when it should only show one.